# Flutter iOS build on XCODE 14.3: PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I'm trying to compile my app on flutter 3.0.5, after porting and updating all the libraries from flutter 2.2.5 due to the need to increase the version of the apple SDK.

I'm having this problem at build time:

`PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

This is my pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: app_inteface_pwa
description: A Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
  flutter: '>=1.12.13+hotfix.4'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.5
  platform: ^3.1.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.10
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  flutter_login: ^4.1.1
  string_validator: ^1.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.0
  json_serializable: ^6.5.4
  firebase_messaging: ^14.3.0
  firebase_core: ^2.8.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.5
  google_sign_in: ^6.0.2
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  #flutter_facebook_auth: ^3.0.0
  #flutter_facebook_sdk: ^1.0.0
  sign_in_with_apple: ^4.3.0
  #flutter_inapp_purchase: ^5.0.0
  #in_app_purchase: 0.5.1+2
  path_provider: ^2.0.14
  connectivity: ^3.0.6
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.1
  crypto: ^3.0.2
  basic_utils: ^5.4.2
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  flutter_offline: ^2.1.0
  async_loader: ^0.1.2
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  flutter_statusbarcolor: ^0.2.3
  webview_flutter: ^4.0.7
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.2+3
  styled_text: ^5.1.0
  flutter_downloader: ^1.10.2
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
  flutter_phoenix: ^1.1.0
  pinch_zoom_image_last: ^0.4.1
  json_annotation: ^4.7.0
  uuid: ^3.0.7
  plugin_platform_interface: ^2.1.4
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.9
  sqflite: ^2.0.3+1
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
  flutter_spinbox: ^0.12.0
  dots_indicator: ^2.1.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  timer_builder: ^2.0.0
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  syncfusion_flutter_sliders: ^21.1.41
  flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.7+1
  screenshot: ^1.3.0
  photofilters: ^3.0.1
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.3
  visibility_detector: ^0.3.3
  multi_image_picker: ^4.8.01
  archive: ^3.3.7
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5
  merge_images: ^2.0.0-nullsafety
  image: ^3.3.0
  image_pixels: ^3.0.0
  flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1
  keep_screen_on: ^2.1.0
  #photo_manager: ^2.0.8
  image_size_getter: ^2.1.2
  file_picker: ^5.2.10
  #facebook_app_events: ^0.16.0
  #flutter_facebook_sdk: ^1.0.0
  #widget_size: ^0.0.3
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
     - assets/_default/
     - assets/fonts/
     - flutter_native_splash.yaml

  fonts:
      - family: Allura
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/Allura/Allura-Regular.ttf
      - family: Anton
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/Anton/Anton.ttf
      - family: IndieFlower
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/IndieFlower/IndieFlower.ttf
      - family: ShadowsIntoLightTwo
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/ShadowsIntoLightTwo/shadows-into-light-two.regular.ttf
      - family: Roboto
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf
            weight: 100
          - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf
            weight: 200
          - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf
            weight: 500
          - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf
            weight: 300
          - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf
            weight: 700
      - family: OpenSans
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Light.ttf
            weight: 100
          - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf
            weight: 100
            style: italic
          - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
            weight: 400
          - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Italic.ttf
            weight: 400
            style: italic
          - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf
            weight: 600
          - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
            weight: 600
            style: italic
          - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
            weight: 700
          - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf
            weight: 700
            style: italic
          - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf
            weight: 800
          - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf
            weight: 800
            style: italic
          


  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

and this instead is the output of the command flutter -run --verbose:

```
 /Users/fabiopaccosi/Projects/Clever Minds/app/RIFOTO/App-iOS-ANDROID/.dart_tool/flutter_build/39666d6bbdfcb5b332855d9ae3fa071f/app.dill --depfile /Users/fabiopaccosi/Projects/Clever
                         Minds/app/RIFOTO/App-iOS-ANDROID/.dart_tool/flutter_build/39666d6bbdfcb5b332855d9ae3fa071f/kernel_snapshot.d --source /Users/fabiopaccosi/Projects/Clever
                         Minds/app/RIFOTO/App-iOS-ANDROID/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart --source package:flutter/src/dart_plugin_registrant.dart
                         -Dflutter.dart_plugin_registrant=file:///Users/fabiopaccosi/Projects/Clever%20Minds/app/RIFOTO/App-iOS-ANDROID/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart package:app_inteface_pwa/main.dart
                         [+9383 ms] Persisting file store
                         [  +25 ms] Done persisting file store
                         [  +14 ms] "flutter assemble" took 24.998ms.
                         [   +5 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 3ms
                         [   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
                         [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
                         [   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
                         [+2816 ms] Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
                         [   +2 ms] don't support null safety:
                         [        ]  - package:flutter_facebook_login
                         [        ]  - package:async_loader
                         [        ]  - package:flutter_icons
                         [        ] For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
                         [ +430 ms] ../../../../../Development/flutter_3_0_5_stable/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_fonts-4.0.3/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:317:42: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
                         [        ] bool _isFileSecure(GoogleFontsFile file, Uint8List bytes) {
                         [        ]                                          ^^^^^^^^^
                         [+6106 ms] ../../../../../Development/flutter_3_0_5_stable/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_fonts-4.0.3/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:317:42: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
                         [        ] bool _isFileSecure(GoogleFontsFile file, Uint8List bytes) {
                         [        ]                                          ^^^^^^^^^
                         [+1094 ms] lib/handler/cart_handler.dart:2873:51: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' which excludes null.
                         [        ]  - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
                         [        ]                     print("[SENDORDER] For page "+element_details!["page_number"].toString()+" send o/m image");
                         [        ]                                                   ^
                         [  +45 ms] lib/screen/item/composed_item/composed_item_screen.dart:1272:39: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'Image' which excludes null.
                         [        ]  - 'Image' is from 'package:image/src/image.dart' ('../../../../../Development/flutter_3_0_5_stable/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image-3.3.0/lib/src/image.dart').
                         [        ]           final mergedImage = m.Image(mask!.width, mask.height);
                         [        ]                                       ^
                         [+2535 ms] ../../../../../Development/flutter_3_0_5_stable/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/multi_image_picker-4.8.01/lib/src/asset.dart:93:21: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type
'ServicesBinding'
                         which excludes null.
                         [        ]  - 'ServicesBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Development/flutter_3_0_5_stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/binding.dart').
                         [        ]     ServicesBinding.instance!.defaultBinaryMessenger
                         [        ]                     ^
                         [        ] ../../../../../Development/flutter_3_0_5_stable/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/multi_image_picker-4.8.01/lib/src/asset.dart:96:23: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type
'ServicesBinding'
                         which excludes null.
                         [        ]  - 'ServicesBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Development/flutter_3_0_5_stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/binding.dart').
                         [        ]       ServicesBinding.instance!.defaultBinaryMessenger
                         [        ]                       ^
                         [        ] ../../../../../Development/flutter_3_0_5_stable/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/multi_image_picker-4.8.01/lib/src/asset.dart:122:21: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type
'ServicesBinding'
                         which excludes null.
                         [        ]  - 'ServicesBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Development/flutter_3_0_5_stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/binding.dart').
                         [        ]     ServicesBinding.instance!.defaultBinaryMessenger
                         [        ]                     ^
                         [        ] ../../../../../Development/flutter_3_0_5_stable/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/multi_image_picker-4.8.01/lib/src/asset.dart:125:23: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type
'ServicesBinding'
                         which excludes null.
                         [        ]  - 'ServicesBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart' ('../../../../../Development/flutter_3_0_5_stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/binding.dart').
                         [        ]       ServicesBinding.instance!.defaultBinaryMessenger
                         [        ]                       ^
                         [   +3 ms] Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
                                    #0      KernelSnapshot.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/common.dart:241:7)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #1      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:839:9)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #2      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:521:21)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #3      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:777:32)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #4      FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:606:16)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #5      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:320:32)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #6      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1183:27)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #12     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #14     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                     
                         [   +4 ms] 
                                    #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
                                    #1      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:337:7)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1183:27)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                                    #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
                                    <asynchronous suspension>
                         Failed to package /Users/fabiopaccosi/Projects/Clever Minds/app/RIFOTO/App-iOS-ANDROID.
                         Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
                     
                         warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to
the script phase, or
                         configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
                         warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to
the script phase, or
                         configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
                         warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to
the script phase, or
                         configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Libuv-gRPC' from project 'Pods')
                         warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to
the script phase, or
                         configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
                         warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to
the script phase, or
                         configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
                         /Users/fabiopaccosi/Projects/Clever Minds/app/RIFOTO/App-iOS-ANDROID/ios/Runner.xcodeproj: warning: Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework Reachability'. Consider
adding an explicit
                         dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
                             note: Target 'Reachability' (in project 'Pods')
                             note: Target 'ReachabilitySwift' (in project 'Pods')
                         warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or
configure it to run in
                         every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
                         warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or
configure it to run in
                         every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
                     
                         Result bundle written to path:
                                /var/folders/k7/wlsmbsjs49s8sq3hsnj922280000gn/T/flutter_tools.A9p7RF/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirlDKeTN/temporary_xcresult_bundle
                     
                     
[+19023 ms] Could not build the application for the simulator.
[   +1 ms] Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
[   +8 ms] "flutter run" took 598.845ms.
[   +8 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:699:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1183:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[ +118 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 117ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

I tried everything from flutter clean to pod deintegrate to restarting to changing to "for install builds only". None solved my problem. I've also tried pod update and install without any success